# Text formatting in exported Freefrom entries

Tags: solspace-freeform

When exporting Freeform entries, I get a plethora of "special characters" making the data almost unusable. (I run an international association and so have more actual special characters than most. Example: acadÃ©mica a presentar tanto aportes teÃ³rico-analÃ­ticos ) Is there a way to export data with the text formatting intact?
Thanks

Comment: So, no help from Solspace?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it seems to work ok for me. Do you have more details you can provide to help me duplicate this issue? Though there was no updates specifically for this in the latest version, I would also upgrade to Freeform 4.1.3 anyway. :)

Also, might be best to create a new support ticket:
http://support.solspace.com/